# Dictionary and Linq : filter the dictionary list

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary variable declared **RegionGridvalues**

```
json = Convert.ToString(modal.RegionGrid);
Dictionary<string, object> RegionGridvalues = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

I have lot of keys like R1_T11 , R1_T12 etc with default values zero.Some has non Initeger like string,Bool etc.
Some of the values are non zero also like 4136,3122 etc.

[image]

I want a Dictionary filtered which has **only non zero values** in it.
I think Linq is best way to get. But I am new to Linq. Can anyone help me on getting Non Zero values from this dictionary.

Comment: Why is the dictionary `<string, object>` and not `Dictionary<string, int>`?

Comment: I guess I do not understand your question.  Why are you using Dictionary<> to parse through Json?  If you are adamant of not using NewtonSoft I think it would be easier to use Dynamics to filter out what you want.

Comment: There's no question here or are you simply hoping that someone will do all the hard work for you?

Comment: I will be passing few other data types as well

Comment: I do not know the syntax. Tats y I have asked this question LIAM

Comment: *I do not know the syntax* === "Please do this for me"

Comment: @KevalRaj I hope this will help you find your way http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonLinq.htm

Comment: Liam, EasyE , I cannot download NewtonSoft in ofc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample begs the question of whether the integer is being stored as an object. Will it always be an integer? If so I would recommend:

```
        var RegionGridvalues = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json)   //deserialize json
                                         .Where(kvp => (int)kvp.Value != 0)               //eliminate entries with 0 value
                                         .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value); //convert results back into dictionary
```

The `where` step has some flexibility depending on the data. Another option would be converting to a string and comparing with "0" (e.g. `(kvp.Value?.ToString() ?? 0) != 0`) ; this would prevent errors if it wasn't stored as an integer. Note the null coalescing to protect against null values.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to do this with Newtonsoft or something similar but if you can't then the following could work to filter Zero values out.

Try -

```
var results = RegionGridvalues.Where(k => k.Value.ToString() != "0");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Janus